# Lack of native laptop resolution into guest OS on VirtualBox (after installing Guest Additions)

Tags: virtualbox, debian, guest-additions

After installing Guest Additions into my guest OS (latest `Debian 6`), I get much more available resolution to choose, but unfortunately there isn't my native laptop resolution - 1440x900. There is 1440x1050.

How could I fix it? My host OS is `Windows7 x64 Home Premium`.

Answer (score 2):

With guest additions installed, the resolution should be automatically adapted to the size of the VirtualBox window displaying the Guest. Hence, when you switch that to Fullscreen, it will switch to the native resolution of your display.